# Error in selecting indeces of a list divisimple by a given value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

a simple code:

```py
suka = pd.Series(range(10))
padla =np.argwhere(suka % 4==0)
```

get the error `Length of passed values is 1, index implies 10`. Why the machine can't return the requested indices? Thank you.

Comment: either make suka an np.array like suka=np.arange(10) or pass an np.array to argwhere like np.argwhere(suka.values %4 ==0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental issues are that the semantics of an array and a `DataFrame` is significantly different (and hence the return of `np.argwhere` shouldn't be boxed) and `numpy` only passing context for `ufuncs` (hence we don't know `np.argwhere` is the function calling `array_wrap`)

This is an issue with the new release of pandas occur in `Pandas 1.0.1` and later versions.

Try `np.flatnonzero()` insted of `np.argwhere()`

Code is :

```py
suka = pd.Series(range(10))
padla =np.flatnonzero(suka % 4==0)
```

for more details go to https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15555 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35334

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using `pandas` the way to identify args is `index`, which is separate to their actual order, so `pandas` approach would be to define `padla` as:

```py
padla = (suka % 4 == 0)
padla = padla.loc[padla].index
```

Roughly speaking equivalent for `numpy` will be:

```py
padla = np.argwhere((suka % 4 == 0).values)
```